# Is there an RPC operation to stop or restart a Corda node remotely?

Tags: corda

In Corda, the node operator is able to issue commands to their node over RPC using the `CordaRPCOps` interface. But there does not appear to be an RPC command for stopping or restarting a node.

How can I stop or restart the node remotely?

Answer (score 1):

As of Corda 3, there is no way to remotely shut down or restart a node. If possible, you can use SSH instead (e.g. `ssh user@host systemctl stop`).

Corda 4 introduces `CordaRPCOps.shutdown`, which shuts the node down immediately without waiting for flows to finish. You should perform a flow drain before invoking this RPC operation.